# Vim "trigger abbreviation" command i_CTRL-] sometimes inserts literal <C-]>

Tags: vim

In insert mode, the command CTRL-] expands an abbreviation without entering a space. So if you set `:abbrev foo bar`, typing `foo<C-]>` will change `foo` to `bar`.

But what happens if you type `bar<C-]>` when you have not set any abbreviations for `bar`? 
In one version of vim (7.3.754), the CTRL-] is ignored. In other versions that I have access to (7.3.0 and 7.2.411), a literal character `^]` is inserted, so you get `bar^]`.

Is this a bug that was fixed? Or is the different treatment because of different compiling options? And is there a way to avoid inserting extraneous `^]`s when I must work in these older vims?

Comment: [This document](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/README) lists all the patches since 7.3. Maybe you'll find what you are looking for. Also, I'd suggest you double check `:h :abbrev`: that feature may or may not have been stable all the time.

Comment: It's seeming like this is a bug. This email discusses the issue: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/103548/

Comment: [Further along the same thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/103534/focus=104444), it is mentioned that inserting a literal `^]` is desired behavior. (Obviously something has changed since then.)

Comment: I can now say for certain that the behavior changed in patch 489 to 7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the behavior changed in [7.3.489](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/34008), which fixed a related bug that prevented `<C-]>` from expanding an abbreviation if the `<C-]>` was inserted via a mapping.

Funny enough, the reason I came across this was because I was defining a mapping

```
inoremap <CR> <C-]><CR><C-U>g
```

The last three characters simply create a new undo point after each `<CR>` pressed in insert mode. Under normal circumstances, pressing enter will also expand an abbreviation if applicable, but not if `<CR>` has been remapped. The `<C-]>` was to forcibly expand abbreviations. It turns out this is the exact mapping that led Yichao Zhou to write the above bugfix.

It isn't a perfect workaround, but by using `if has("patch489")` when defining the map, you can at least degrade gracefully to older versions of vim. Pressing enter will not expand abbreviations, but at least it won't insert `<C-]>`.